# stripping \n from list wont work

Tags: python

I have created a file Alpha.txt with these numbers inside

```
1.2, 4.3, 7,0
3, 5, 8.2,9
4, 3, 8,5.6
8, 4, 3,7.4
```

everytime i try to strip the /n created when making these into lists, i return this error.

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

I am aware this question has been asked before, but for some reason i cannot get my code to work with all the solutions already online. Sorry for the repeat.

here is my code

```
def main():
    my_list = [line.split(',') for line in open("Alpha.txt")]
    print(my_list)
    for element in my_list:
        element = element.strip()
    print(element)

main()
```

removing the `for element in my_list` and down, I get this output:

```
[['1.2', ' 4.3', ' 7', '0\n'], ['3', ' 5', ' 8.2', '9\n'], 
['4', ' 3', ' 8', '5.6\n'], ['8', ' 4', ' 3', '7.4\n']]
```

which is great, minus the \n part....

Comment: As a side note: `/n` is two characters, a forward slash followed by a letter. `\n` is one character, a newline. If you mix them up, you're going to have a lot of problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.split` method of a string always returns a list:

```
>>> "a b c d e".split()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>>
```

Thus, the items in `my_list` will be lists.

Perhaps you should try this:

```
my_list = [line.strip().split(',') for line in open("Alpha.txt")]
```

Unlike the `.split` method, the `.strip` one returns a copy of the string, not a list.

Comment: ahhh thanks so much, i wasnt aware that i could combine strip and split like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your `my_list` is a list of lists of strings—to put it more clearly, it's a list of rows, each of which is a list of columns, each of which is a string.

So, each `element` in `my_list` is a row—a list of columns.

You can't strip a list, only a string. If you want to strip *all* the columns in a row, you have to do that explicitly:

```
for element in my_list:
    for column in element:
        column = column.strip()
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
for element in my_list:
    element = [column.strip() for column in element]
```

But it's worth noting that just reassigning that `column` or `element` variable each time through the loop won't do much good if you never *use* it inside the loop. Your original code has the same problem. If you're trying to change `my_list` in place, this isn't the way to do it (and you probably don't actually want to, anyway).

Meanwhile, as iCodez points out, you probably *don't* want to strip each column here, just the last column… which you can do just as easily by stripping the line before splitting it, which makes for much simpler code.